Summation of reciprocals of nth roots of unity

I let the term inside the summation be equal to x, put $a$ in terms of x and used $a^n$=1 but because I have not done binomial yet I got stuck at that point. I was thinking of opening using binomial and using vieta theorem to find summation of all values of b which would give me the answer. I need help with the expansion of $x^n[(2-1/x)^n-1]=0$

Can you solve it for $n=4$? Working small cases can often help build intuition for the general form.

Let $f(z)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ whose roots are $1, \alpha, \ldots, \alpha^{n-1}$.  What is $f(z)$?
Next, show that the polynomial $g(z) = f(2-z)$ has roots $2-1, 2-\alpha, \ldots, 2-\alpha^{n-1}$.
Next, show that the rational function $h(z) = g(1/z)$ has roots $\frac{1}{2-1}, \frac{1}{2-\alpha}, \ldots, \frac{1}{2-\alpha^{n-1}}$.
Next, suppose we may write $h(z)$ in the form $p(z)/q(z)$ for polynomials $p$, $q$.  What do the roots of $h$ imply about the roots of $p$?
Write down $p(z)$.
What do you know about the sum of the roots of a polynomial in terms of its coefficients?

This approach seems more clearer compared to mine, I will go try it. For the sum of roots of a polynomials in terms of its coefficients, I know it's like summation of all roots taken at one time is -b/a then take at 2 times is c/a and so on. Thank you

@Toshiv Be careful:  remember that the sum ranges from $i = 1$ to $n-1$, so the first root $\alpha^0 = 1$ is excluded.
